# Set many annotations in MapKit

Tags: xcode, mapkit

What is the best way to set many annotations (company's 30 branches) in MapKit?

I checked the "MapCallouts" project in the manual, but its not practical to create 30 classes (one for each annotation)!

Preferred a sample code for at least 1 annotation :)

Regards